# Solve the diophantine equation 71x +29y = 101

Tags: diophantine-equations

Solve the diophantine equation 71x +29y = 101

**1.Euclidean algorithm**

71 = 29*2 + 13

29 = 29*2 + 3

13 = 3*4 + 1

3 = 3*1 + 0

GCD(71,29) = 1

**2. Write as linear equation (Euclidean algorithm backwards)**

1 = 13 - 4*3

3 = 29 - 2*13

13 = 71 - 2*29

1 = 13 - 4*3 =

= 13 -4*(29 - 2*13)

= 9*13 -4*29

= 9*(71-2*29)-4*29

= 9*71 - 22*29

1 = 9*71 - 22*29 -> (**write in the form 71x +29y = 101**)

71(9) + 29(-22) = 1

71(909) + 29(-2222) = 101

71*909 + 29*(-2222) + 29*71n - 71*29n = 101

71(909-29n) + 29(-2222 + 71n) = 101

**x = 909  - 29n**

**y = -2222 + 71n**

Now that's my solution. But the correct solution should be:

x = -29n - 19

y = 71n + 50

Comment: The $y$ solutions are the same since $-2222\equiv 50\pmod{71}$, but the $x$ solution is a bit off (I haven't scanned through your work yet, probably an arithmetic mistake).

Comment: I think you meant $x=-29n-19$ because then both solutions are equivalently correct.

Comment: Yes i meant - 19, but why are they  equivalently correct?

Comment: If the solution for $x$ has $-19$ instead of $-9$, then these are the same since $909\equiv -19\pmod{29}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions are correct. They are just different parametrizations of the same set of $(x,y)$. You have got $$x=909-29n,y=-2222+71n$$ for any integer $n$. You can plug any integer for $n$ and still got valid solution. Especially we can replace $n$ with $n+c$ for some constant $c$, shifting the parameter and still get valid solutions. Doing this we would get $$x=909-29c-29n,y=-2222+71c+71n.$$ Now you can see that choosing $c=32$ gives $$x=-19-29n, y=50+71n,$$ the expected solution. You might think of this as just inserting as many multiples of $29$ or $71$ as needed to make the parametrization simpler, but keep in mind that the parameter $n$ is same in both equations for $x$ and $y$, so you need to change both accordingly. Perhaps sometimes it might be also useful to view the solution in vector form instead:

$$(x,y)=(909,-2222)+n\cdot(-29,71).$$

Comment: How do we know that using c = -32 and c = 32 for both cases gives us the "best  answer"

Comment: There is no "best answer", it just explains how to get answer that your book/teacher got to. But still you could aim to get for example as small numbers as possible, which looks a bit better than large numbers, in that sense you would try $c$'s that minimize $909-29c$ and $-2222+71c$ in absolute value (by the way $c=-32$ does not give you anything "nice")

Comment: Ok, if a find a small number that looks good for y when c is something, must I then use the same c for x? (When using A mod B = (A + K*B) mod B for any integer K)

Comment: Yes, it is the same $c$ as $n$ is the same $n$ in both equations. We have just substituted something into $n$, and you cannot substitute two different things for same $n$.